# Cerrar la consola de windows desde python

Tags: python, windows, consola

estoy desarrollando un programita que utiliza como interfaz con el usuario la consola de Windows.. Mi problema es que necesito que, una vez finalizado el programa, se cierre la consola automáticamente...

Intenté hacerlo con `os.system('exit')` y con `sys.exit()` y no la cierra, solamente termina la ejecución de python y deja abierta la consola de windows...

Lo único que funcionó fue utilizar `os.system('taskkill /f /im cmd.exe')` pero me cerraría todas las consolas que se encuentren abiertas y no es la idea...

Desde ya muchas Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo estás haciendo para ejecutar la aplicación? ¿Abres una consola y escribes `python.exe el_script.py`? o ¿Tienes un `.bat` o `.cmd` con el comando?

Comment: Por ahora, mientras lo escribo, cmd>py script.py, pero la idea una vez terminado todo es generar un .exe con py2exe para cada script (son varios módulos separados), entre ellos uno es el que tendrá las opciones para entrar a cada módulo... este último probablemente sea una ventana bien simple hecha con tkinter o una página html donde habrá un botón para cada .exe

Comment: cómo inicias la ejecución del programa?

Answer (score 0):

De esa forma no se va a cerrar la ventana, porque al abrir manualmente `cmd` se crea un proceso independiente de una consola que está esperando órdenes. Al ejecutar Python, lo hace correctamente, pero al salir del script la consola seguirá esperando más órdenes.
Quizás se puede calcular el PID de la consola actual para después mandarle un `taskkill /F /PID el_pid`, pero creo que no vale la pena el esfuerzo.

**[1]** Si Python está ***correctamente instalado*** (en `C:\Python310`, para todos los usuarios, y agregado a **PATH**) puedes darle doble clic directamente al script o crear un acceso directo al mismo. Una vez se termine la ejecución, la ventana se cerrará.

**[1.5]** Si el script abre un manejador de ventanas gráficas tipo Tkinter, QT, etc... entonces al script que arranca la ejecución le puedes poner la extensión **.pyw** en vez de py (`script.pyw`). Esto es para que no se abra la ventana negra CMD.

**[2]** Puedes crear un `.bat` (o `.cmd`) que abre un `cmd` que a su vez ejecuta el script `py`. Al finalizar el script se cerrará la consola:

```
@ECHO OFF
python.exe C:\ruta\de\el_script.py
exit
```

[IMPORTANTE] Cuidado con las rutas relativas, sobre todo si el script lee o escribe archivos. Para asegurarse el correcto comportamiento, usar rutas absolutas (no recomendado por portabilidad), o mejor aún:

```
# Cambiar el directorio de trabajo a la ruta del script.
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias por la respuesta.. cuando termine el programa entonces voy a probar de alguna de las formas que me comentas... Saludos